# How to create a JFace TreeViewer with multi column?

Tags: java, swt, jface, treeviewer

I was able to create JFace multi column `TreeViewer`, with a single content provider. SO it causing same data in all columns.

How can I set multi column with different data or have multiple content provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have several content providers in a single viewer. But you can either use [`ITableLabelProvider`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ITableLabelProvider.html) which lets text and image depend on the index of the column, 
or have different label providers for every column using [`TreeViewerColumn`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/TreeViewerColumn.html) and [`ColumnLabelProvider`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ColumnLabelProvider.html).

Answer (score 0):

The program in the [link](https://github.com/vogella/eclipse.platform.ui/blob/master/examples/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet026TreeViewerTabEditing.java) shows all possible Tree viewer related implementations